# Eclipse visual indicator for potential null pointer access?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I have something like the below:

```
String test = myObject.getStringProperty().toUpperCase()
```

Is there any way I could get eclipse to show a visual warning that it is a potential null pointer exception? I tried `Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Null Analysis` and setting the `Potential null pointer access` setting to `Error` then did the required rebuild of the project, but I did not see any visual indicator on that line of code above. Note that that is basically the only code (no null check earlier on getStringProperty() has been done anywhere)

Comment: Can `myObject` or `getStringProperty` ever be null?

Comment: Yes. In my project `myObject` is actually a JPA entity and the `getStringProperty()` corresponds to a nullable column in the corresponding database table representing the entity.

Comment: But can it **return** null if you look solely at the way it's written?

Comment: @nitind not quite sure what you mean. It (getStringProperty) can  return null and did, as it crashed my program during runtime.